# How to change the candle color of a candles which satisfy my candle criteria/definition in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

Here is my current code:

```
strategy("Big Candle", overlay = true, shorttitle="Candle Boom", initial_capital = 100000)

//Bullish Body
bhu1 = (close-open) > 0.00102 
bullColor = #095616
bearColor = #ac0011

plotshape(bhu1 , style = shape.arrowup , location = location.belowbar , text = "Bull")

plotcandle(bhu1, color=bullColor)
```

I'm trying to change the color of all the candles which meet the bhu1 definition shown above (candles with big bodies basically)
I've tried many variations trying to get this to work: e.g. plotcandle(bhu1 ? color=bullColor) etc and many more but I can't get it to work.

Error: Cannot call `plotcandle` with arguments (series__bool, color); available overloads: plotcandle(series, series, series, series, string, series__color, color, literal__bool, string) => void; plotcandle(fun_arg__<arg_open_type>, fun_arg__<arg_high_type>, fun_arg__<arg_low_type>, fun_arg__<arg_close_type>, string, fun_arg__<arg_color_type>, color, literal__bool, string) => void
Script 'Candle alert' has been saved

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

`plotcandle()` doesn't modify the existing chart candles, it creates a new, separate candle set, so it won't help you with this. To specify the color of the main chart candles' bodies, you can use `barcolor()`:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Big Candle", overlay = true, shorttitle="Candle Boom", initial_capital = 100000)
//Bullish Body
bhu1 = (close-open) > 0.00102 
bullColor = #095616
bearColor = #ac0011
barcolor(bhu1 ? bullColor : na)
```